# How to extract value of nested object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extract all links IDs of the object array shown below. This is how I was trying to get that:

```
const linkIDs = array
  .filter(d => d.links)
  .map(d => d.links)
```

But this gives me a nested array, which is not what I wanted.

```
[
  {
    "id: "1",
    "links": [
        {
            "id" : "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ",
            "type" : "article"
        },
      {
            "id" : "PGhkJXDn59y87paiZ",
            "type" : "article"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id: "2",
    "links": [
        {
            "id" : "GhkJXpaiZDn59y87P",
            "type" : "article"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

So in this example I need the result

```
[ "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ", "PGhkJXDn59y87paiZ", "GhkJXpaiZDn59y87P" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a more readable syntax in plain JS:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "links": [
        {
            "id" : "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ",
            "type" : "article"
        },
       {
            "id" : "PGhkJXDn59y87paiZ",
            "type" : "article"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "links": [
        {
            "id" : "GhkJXpaiZDn59y87P",
            "type" : "article"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
];
var result = data.filter(e => e.links)
                 .map(e => e.links)
                 .flat()
                 .map(e => e.id)
                
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do like bellow, without using any other library.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "links": [
        {
            "id" : "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ",
            "type" : "article"
        },
       {
            "id" : "PGhkJXDn59y87paiZ",
            "type" : "article"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "links": [
        {
            "id" : "GhkJXpaiZDn59y87P",
            "type" : "article"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
];

var result = data.filter(e => e.links)
                 .map(e => e.links.map(link => link.id))
                 .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
                
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to produce your array before mapping. [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in Js is very useful function ;)

```js
arr = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "links": [
        {
            "id" : "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ",
            "type" : "article"
        },
      {
            "id" : "PGhkJXDn59y87paiZ",
            "type" : "article"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "links": [
        {
            "id" : "GhkJXpaiZDn59y87P",
            "type" : "article"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
];

var result = arr.filter(a=>a.links).reduce((acc, a) => {
 return acc.concat(a.links)
}, []).map(a=>a.id);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's flatMap() , where each filtered item is transformed using map().

**DEMO**

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "links": [
      {
        "id": "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ",
        "type": "article"
      },
      {
        "id": "PGhkJXDn59y87paiZ",
        "type": "article"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "links": [
      {
        "id": "GhkJXpaiZDn59y87P",
        "type": "article"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
];
var result =  _.flatMap(data, item => 
  _(item.links)
    .map(v => (v.id))
    .value()
);
           
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: The output is different, also, need to use another lib.

Comment: @DanielTran Updated, check